# Producing XML using SQL Server which uses Excel tags

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to achieve the following output:

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s87">
    <Data ss:Type="String">N</Data>
    <NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/>
</Cell>
```

My SQL code looks like this:

```
SELECT
    'String' AS 'Data/@type',
    [Submit]  AS [Data], 
    NULL
FROM 
    dbo.[XML_Table]
FOR XML PATH ('Row')
```

The resulting output looks like this

```
<Row>
    <Data type="String">Y</Data>
</Row>
```

How do I go about making it look like this:

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s87">
    <Data ss:Type="String">Y</Data>
    <NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/>
</Cell>
```

Thank you

sample table output showing all fields but i am just using the submit field as an example:

[image]

Comment: What does your data in your table actually look liike?

Comment: Also, your output that you get suggests that `Submit` has a value of `'Y'`, but in your expected output it needs a value of `'N'`?

Comment: Sorry the output should be 'Y', i copied the wrong row results, i will see if i can get the table here but it does contain company data so i would need to mask that, what i am getting at though is how i add <Cell ss:StyleID="s87"> and "ss:" etc to the output using sql to get all the relevant bits i need for the output to look the same if you know what i mean?

Comment: Sample data is fine, it doesn't have to be real, just representative of the results you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can get pretty close using this code - assuming you have all the element and attribute values that get output in your XML inside some table in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @Input TABLE (StyleId VARCHAR(20), 
                      CellType VARCHAR(20),
                      CellData VARCHAR(20), 
                      CellName VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @Input (StyleId, CellType, CellData, CellName)
VALUES ('s87', 'String', 'Y', '_FilterDatabase');

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('urn:test' AS ss)
SELECT
    StyleId AS '@ss:StyleID',
    CellType AS 'Data/@ss:Type',
    CellData AS 'Data',
    CellName AS 'NamedCell/@ss:Name',
    '' AS 'NamedCell'
FROM
    @Input
FOR XML PATH('Cell')
```

This results in an output of:

```
<Cell xmlns:ss="urn:test" ss:StyleID="s87">
  <Data ss:Type="String">Y</Data>
  <NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"></NamedCell>
</Cell>
```

I don't see how you could "skip" actually declaring the XML namespace alias, though - so that'll show up on your `<Cell>` toplevel node.

Comment: Thank you this, is exactly what i wanted, i am guessing i can add a bit more to this as some fields seem to have an index attribute as well etc? and some don't have the filtered database.